# React Native: Read local image as Base64 string to send it in JSON

Tags: reactjs, react-native, requirejs, base64, require

In React Native I'm trying to load an image stored at a **relative path as a base64 string**, but the `require` returns `3` as response instead of the image source.

I'm sure the path is correct, and I the `require` command works elsewhere in my Reacy Native JSX code to load images from the same relative path (`<Image source={require('../resources/examplecar.jpg')}>`) without any problem.

How to get a local image source from the filesystem as base64 string to send it in JSON?

```
var body = {
    path: '../resources/examplecar.jpg',
    data: {
        image: require('../resources/examplecar.jpg'),
    }
}
```

Comment: Did it work? I also have same issue

Comment: The workaround that I posted in the answer worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using RNFS plugin it is possible to access the React Native assets and convert the data into a range of formats including Base64.

```
imageData = await RNFS.readFile(RNFS.MainBundlePath+"/assets/resources/examplecar.jpg", 'base64').then();
```

Comment: RNFS.MainBundlePath undefined 
why could it be

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a variable in require. It won't work for image source in rn.
Do

```
  image: require('../resources/examplecar.jpg')
```

Comment: That helps me in finding the solution, but it was a typo. The main problem is that `require('../resources/examplecar.jpg')` evaluates to `3`

Comment: It will console log it like that. But if you use it as a source for your Image component it will work.

Comment: The thing is that I'm not using it as a source for Image component, but as part of a string in JSON